# How to use SQL to count events in the first week

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having, dense-rank

I'm trying to write a SQL query, which says how many logins each user made in their first week.

Assume, for the purpose of this question, that I have a table with at least `user_id` and `login_date`. I'm trying to produce an output table with `user_id` and `num_logins_first_week`

Comment: You may assume that, but I do not believe my code merits sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation to get the first date for each user.  Then `join` in the logins and aggregate:

```
select t.user_id, count(*) as num_logins_first_week
from t join
     (select user_id, min(login_date) as first_login_date
      from t
      group by user_id
     ) tt
     on tt.user_id = t.user_id and
        t.login_date >= tt.first_login_date and
        t.login_date < tt.first_login_date + interval 7 day
group by t.user_id;
```

Comment: This was what I suspected, but I was hoping there was a way to do it without a subquery. Maybe not.